# Do I really need yosemite for watchkit app development?

Tags: osx-mavericks, watchkit, osx-yosemite

I'm using Mavericks still as I dont like the Yosemite UI. I've got the latest XCode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 available for Mavericks, so it is really necessary?

Comment: I can't remember if Yosemite is required for IOS development - it is for creating OSX 10.10+ apps - but the latest version is 6.3 and 8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always recommended that you keep your OS to the latest update especially if you're doing any sort of development. It's much safer and there's a less chance of you running into compatibility problems. Just curious, why do you want to stick with Maverick?

Comment: i hate the yosemite ui.

Comment: I also have some hardware that doesnt have drivers for yosemite.

Comment: Well, If you've got hardware/driver problems, there's nothing you can do about it. Apple requires you have the latest XCode and that's that.

Comment: i never got a proper answer for which versions of XCode supported WC, people assumed i needed Yosemite, and that it was needed for WC development. Ive upgraded now anyway, but 6.2 beta on Mavericks did work.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got the latest XCode 6.2 and iOS 8.2

The latest is Xcode 6.3.1 or Xcode 6.4 beta, and iOS 8.3 or iOS 8.4 beta, so you do *not* have the latest. And those versions run only on Yosemite. Get over it.

Comment: But Apple won't accept any App Store submissions built with anything but the latest Xcode, so "latest for Mavericks" is irrelevant. You may not like the truth but it stays the truth.